# Exclude webpages containing specific string while recursively dowload a website using wget

Tags: wget

I'm trying to scrape a website recursively, but I want to exclude some webpages under that domain, containing the string "unnecessary pages". The string is not present in the URL. Here's the original command to build from:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://www.website.com
```

For example; I want to scrape the wikipedia. But I want to exclude articles that contain the keyword "drugs".

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with the following options. It will scrape a site beginning at any path you choose to start and will exclude directories you have specified in LIST:

```
$ wget \
    --recursive \
    --no-clobber \
    --page-requisites \
    --html-extension \
    --convert-links \
    --restrict-file-names=windows \
    --domains somesite.tld \
    --no-parent \
    --exclude-directories=LIST \
        www.somesite.tld/path/to/start
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I meant that the string "unnecessary pages" was located on the website, but not in the link. Like this webpage. The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355038/exclude-webpages-containing-specific-string-while-recursely-dowload-a-website-u/, but your name, David C. Rankin, is only present within the actual page.

Comment: No, your question was good, (my eyes were bad) I see what you originally wanted and wget doesn't provide that level of fine-grained control to accept/reject a page based on whether or not it contains a specific link. From a reality standpoint, to test whether the page has the unwanted link, you will have to download it anyway, so your best bet is to scrape the site and then run grep recursively on the resulting download and delete any pages containing the link like that. You could do some recursive `lynx -dump` before hand, identify the pages and exclude in wget that way, but its downloaded.